# How to set imageview.toImage() as html image src in webview?

Tags: android, iphone, image, webview, titanium

any idea to set imageview.toImage() as img src in html of a webview.

let suppose I have an imageview (having some image in it).okay imageview.toimage() is treated as an image object in titanium. now what i need is i want to set

```
webview.html='<html><img src="here i want to put obove imageview.toimage()"></html>';
```

I tried many way anyone have experience of it please guide me.

regards:ali

Answer (score 0):

save it to a file and assigne the file's url path OR base64Encode the image and provide that as the value for the src parameter

Comment: Hi Aron i Did something like this.                                          var img= Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory +        Ti.Filesystem.separator + 'newflower.jpg';                                 aWebView.html='<html><body><img src="'+img+'" /></body></html>';         But its showing webview as empty.but works fine when i assign img to  an image view.Please guide me what is the issue.Thanks.

Comment: try putting the image in the same directory as the html file and see if that works, dont set the path at all

Answer (score 0):

you might try to convert the image into a base64 blob text and use it as css background image data :

```
background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,'+Ti.Utils.base64encode(imageview.toImage()).getText()+'\');
```